# Once saved, is there a way to change the subject line

Tags: gmail

I get an automated reply from a program but the automated subject does not reflect the content of the email. I would like to change the subject line on the saved messages so I can easily tell what is in the email. Is there a way to do this without having to reply to myself and change the subject in the reply?

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. The only way you can achieve this is if you change it in the said program email template. Otherwise, you are stuck with either keeping it as it is or resending it to yourself and editing the subject.